# How to use redux in class component using react with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How to use redux in class component using react with typescript.
1.) useDispatch,useSelector how to use it in class base components react typescript

[image: Initially I created one store.tsx]

And here I get the data from store.tsx using useSelector but this is a class component(App.tsx)[image: Using the redux in class component]

then, I dispatched here(App.jsx)
[image: I don't know how to dispatch here]

Comment: you can't use hook in class component pls find a here a complete example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-toolkit-class-components-forked-f82o7o?file=/src/index.tsx)

Comment: Please don't share images of your code. Copy the code into the post itself instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use higher order component **connect** which is provided by react-redux library.

first import it

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
```

then to access state use the function

```
const mapStateToProps = (props) => {
  return {
    api: props.api,
  };
};
```

and for action use

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    action: () => dispatch(action),
  };
};
```

and at the end export it like

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent);
```

to use it simply access through props, for example

```
const data = props.api
```

and same for dispatch

```
function addData () {
props.action()
}
```